# Scrambled Nautilus windows during dynamic resize

Tags: gnome, nautilus, video, hardware, gpu-driver

If I dynamically resize my Nautilus windows the picture inside of said video becomes scrambled during the resize, and only during the resize. When I let off my mouse button all video returns to normal. What causes this and how do I avoid it? There is no other video scrambling issues during my working sessions in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

Comment: Is it just Nautilus that's GNOME? If you use the standard Unity interface, try the Unity Tweak tool, which can help turn off or on some animation and other GUI features that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, just GNOME Nautilus. Looked at tweak tool settings but couldn't get anything to help much.